# Emacs hook when attempting to write a read-only buffer

Tags: emacs, hook, perforce, readonly

I'm looking to have a hook that triggers when a buffer marked read-only is attempted to be written. It's more of a convenience than necessary, I'm aware of C-x C-q which is currently where the function triggers (a Perforce p4-edit command), but it seems cleaner to do this when I begin to type (Much like the Visual Studio P4 plugin I believe).

Any help much appreciated as I've ran out of ideas.

Thanks,
Jon.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error which you can catch:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Handling-Errors.html

Comment: Hi, thanks you put me on the right track.

`(defun p4-write-attempt (data context caller)
          ; If it's a read-only-buffer and you wrote to it
  (if (eq 'buffer-read-only (car data))
                  ; And the user wants to checked out
   (if (y-or-n-p "Checkout in Perforce?")
    (p4-edit (buffer-file-name))
  )
 )
  )

(setq command-error-function 'p4-write-attempt)`

Comment: An other possible way is [advising](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) self-insert-command and catch the error there.